# Git. "Peek" at changes other people pushed?

Tags: git

I'm yet fresh to Git.

Is there any way to see changes other people pushed to repo since the last time I made a merge to my local machine?

I basically need an command line equivalent of Atlassian SourceTree feature of "looking ahead" at commits people pushed since my last merge without fetching those commits (?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the commits without actually updating your working copy. Just use `git fetch` and then browse the various refs it pulls down (the refs are named `<remotename>/<branchname>` - e.g. `origin/master`).

```
# Fetch an updated list of commits from the remote, without merging
$ git fetch origin

# View the log output for the version of 'master' we just fetched from 'origin'
$ git log origin/master
```

Comment: thx. I was unclear if `fetch` is needed here or git has some other interesting mechanism to do it... However I see SourceTree [does it itself](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/47459/please-make-sourcetree-automatically-refresh-the-remote-status-on-opening-a-repo).